# How to mask a rotated rectangle from an image?

Tags: python, opencv

I have an image that I need to mask some portion of it. The portion is a rotated rectangle. When I pass on the arguments of top-left corner and bottom-right corner to the function `cv.rectangle()`, it does not form a rotated rectangle, instead, it draws a rectangle with no tilt. However, I want to mask a rotated rectangle in an image and I have all the four coordinates of the rectangle. Is there any way to do this? Thank you. Any help is appreciated. I am using OpenCV in python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To draw a rotated rectangle, extract the four corners into a contour, then use [cv::drawContours](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d6/d6e/group__imgproc__draw.html#ga746c0625f1781f1ffc9056259103edbc)

```
cv::RotatedRect rr(cv::Point(x, y), cv::Size(w, h), angle);
cv::Point2f pts[4];
rr.points(pts);
std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point>> contours;
contours.push_back(std::vector<cv::Point>());
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) contours[0].push_back(pts[i]);
cv::drawContours(image, contours, 0, cv::Scalar::all(255), -1);
```

oops, that's C++ ... but transcoding to python should be straightforward :)
Section 7 of [this tutorial](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/dd/d49/tutorial_py_contour_features.html) has what you need.